# I can't edit the design of my android tv application with android studio

Tags: android-tv

I am creating a new project for android tv.
I have no written code.
I can't modify the design of the application

```
error message: unknown fragment
```

more details of the error:

```
A <fragment> tag allows a layout file to dynamically include different layouts at runtime. At layout editing time the specific layout to be used is not known. You can choose which layout you would like previewed while editing the layout.
```

Error Image

[image]

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_browse_fragment"
    android:name="com.example.milchycompany.myapplication.MainFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="tv"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

code MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

Help please to be able to create my first android tv application

Comment: What have you tried already to make it work?That might help those who are trying to answer your question, by narrowing it down.

Comment: add more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing your com.example.milchycompany.myapplication.MainFragment extends from BrowseFragment. That Fragment dynamically includes layouts that are part of the Leanback library such as R.layout.lb_browse_fragment as well as Adapters to programmatically generate the other layouts. Because of that, it's not designed to be edited in the layout editor. Instead, you would call the various setters to adjust the UI such as

```
setTitle(getString(R.string.browse_title));
```

and

```
setBrandColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.your_brand_color));
```

If your MainFragment doesn't extend from BrowseFragment, then you should open it and see what layout is being set in its onCreateView method and modify that layout instead.

Comment: Help, in setBranColor() show in red "cannot resolve method setBrandColor(int) help me please

Comment: You should call that within your "MainFragment" that extends BrowseFragment. Typically, people override onActivityCreated and call it there.

Comment: Thank you and merry Christmas, I am grateful for your help